# JNI on Android, how to pass int from c to java

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I have a C function, I simply returns an integer, as follows:

```
 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_project_ScreenPosition(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz){
   int i=1;
   return i;
 }
```

I call this function in the way of an Activity onCreateContextMenu Android, as follows:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
 menu.setHeaderTitle("TryMenu");

 int a=ScreenPosition();
 return;
}
```

But all crash

Comment: Can you post here code of the Class declaring the native method?

Comment: Also error stack trace might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you compiled your C code into a library called libmyCode.so you need to explicitly load the shared library code into the process using this Java call:

System.loadLibrary("myCode");

before calling any JNI methods.

If you changed your API (the method declarations in Java with the "native" keyword) you absolutely need to run the javah utility again.

If you use Eclipse, then after running javah and ndk-build, it is a good idea to refresh Eclipse's view of the filesystem by pressing F5.  Eclipse will then detect the newly built library code.

If it is still not working, please share the output from logcat, including all the output that appears from the moment you install the app to the phone, the stack dump and any error or warning messages